# Lots of undefined symbols - GLFW

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opengl, glfw

I have downloaded glfw on my Mac and decided to start experimenting. I installed it by using cmake to generate a unix makefile, then ran `make && make install`. I also did `brew install glfw3` and started working.

The first thing I did was go to InitWithData's FPS tutorial number 1. Coded, compiled it, worked fine. But when I went to tutorial 3, my xcode started talking about `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:`
I tried backtracking to the first tutorial, but then it seemed to be corrupt. I then looked over at this tutorial on the glfw 3 documentation and found this code.

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
static void error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
    fputs(description, stderr);
}
static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}
int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;
    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);
    if (!glfwInit())
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Simple example", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        float ratio;
        int width, height;
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
        ratio = width / (float) height;
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(-ratio, ratio, -1.f, 1.f, 1.f, -1.f);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glRotatef((float) glfwGetTime() * 50.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor3f(1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
        glVertex3f(-0.6f, -0.4f, 0.f);
        glColor3f(0.f, 1.f, 0.f);
        glVertex3f(0.6f, -0.4f, 0.f);
        glColor3f(0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
        glVertex3f(0.f, 0.6f, 0.f);
        glEnd();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

But, it still doesn't work. with these errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_glfwCreateWindow", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_glfwDestroyWindow", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_glfwGetFramebufferSize", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_glfwGetTime", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_glfwInit", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_glfwMakeContextCurrent", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_glfwPollEvents", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_glfwSetErrorCallback", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_glfwSetKeyCallback", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_glfwSetWindowShouldClose", referenced from:
      key_callback(GLFWwindow*, int, int, int, int) in main.o
  "_glfwSwapBuffers", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_glfwTerminate", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_glfwWindowShouldClose", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Anyone know what's going on? I've tried reinstalling glfw already.
(Remember, xcode4 -macosx

Comment: It looks like you either left your glfw library off the link line, or you compiled the glfw library for an architecture other than x86_64.

Comment: As for the second, no. What do you mean 'off the link line'?

Comment: "off the link line": meaning on the command that links your program (the gcc/clang command that finally turns your .o's into an executable), the appropriate `-l` (maybe `-lglfw`) is not present.

Comment: Well, I'm using xcode, so how do I see and edit the command? And I don't know if this affects it, but I'm not using dylibs but instead the header files generated by make. Does this remove the need to use that specialized command?

Comment: Using headers is not for linking, it's for compiling. Compiling just converts your source to object but doesn't make it runnable; linking makes objects runnable by linking libraries in (among other things). Adding the option is just a matter of specifying the right library (for example, within the Xcode project configuration); from your answer, it sounds like you've got that covered though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. Well, it seems I have solved my problem. I don't know why, but...

```
deleted libglfw.dylib
deleted unix makefile installed headers
recreated libglfw.a (portable, non system)
added all the dependencies (cocoa, iokit, corevideo, opengl)
```

I have no idea why the dylibs and makefile generated things weren't working. If anyone could explain why....